# Word for "make a master of"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I work in Software, and we use ["master/slave"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master-slave_%28technology%29) as terms.  We had one task where we needed to make one software component the "master" of another "slave".  The task's name was "Mastering Component X".

To me, this doesn't make sense because it sounds like someone is becoming proficient in the subject of "Component X".  What we want to say is that we want "Component X" to be  authoritative, or make it a master of "Component Y".

Is there a single word that can express this meaning, or shall I use a phrase like "Make Component X authoritative"?

Comment: You could use any of the following: *master*, *enslave*, *tame*, *subdue*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term **[promote](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/promote?showCookiePolicy=true)** is often used to indicate that something has moved to a higher, more powerful level

> to raise to a higher rank, status, degree, etc

Similarly **[elevate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/elevate)**

> to raise in rank or status; promote

You could say Component X has been *promoted* over Component Y or *elevated over Component Y.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the slave **subordinate** to the master or have the master **suborn** the slave.  I'm in software too, and in a large company I used to work for that quite likely makes the operating system you're using (as long as it doesn't rhyme with sack or biscuits) set down the law that we were no longer able to use the master / slave pair and we had to come up with something more PC.

Answer (score 1):

I would say ***to crown*** in the sense of "make king over."  This would avoid the ambiguity inherent in *master*.

Component X *was crowned* over Component Y.